# Pass a variable from a get query in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables

I am trying to pass the value of a parameter outside a `$.get` jQuery in javascript. I read that I should somehow do that in synchronous mode but I couldn't find a solution.

Here is my code:

```
var flag;
var t = $.get("mutalyzer.php?id="+variation.value, function(data) {
    flag=data;
});
document.write(flag);
```

where I get **undefined** as a result.

Thanks!

Comment: Put the `document.write()` inside the `$.get()` callback, and don't take suggestions to use synchronous ajax seriously.

Answer (score 3):

write it inside the callback function

try this

```
var t = $.get("mutalyzer.php?id="+variation.value, function(data) {
   //this is the callback function and runs when get gets  completed
   flag=data;
   document.write(flag); 
 });
```

Comment: it should be noted that calling `document.write()` in there will indeed show the value returned, but the net result will be that that will be all that's left of the original page.

Comment: HI, actually i want to use the variable flag in other functions in my code, not only print it.

Comment: then you need to pass that inside the callback function..... calling it outside is not a good idea since you function  may get called before the ajax returns something